# How to brew 1-3 servings of coffee with as little waste as possible?

Tags: brewing-process

I'm looking for a quick/easy way to brew coffee in small servings, usually one cup. However I am looking to make no waste (except for the used coffee grinds). Is it possible to use a teapot like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06Y8RRP8P) to brew? Maybe similar to a [pour over](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000P4D5F8) method.

I have a grinder for beans, and I have a french press (but am looking for an alternative).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always try a mesh pour over like [this one](https://www.banggood.com/Stainless-Steel-Pour-Over-Coffee-Dripper-Reusable-Double-Mesh-Coffee-Maker-Cone-Filter-p-1178093.html?gmcCountry=CA&currency=CAD&createTmp=1&utm_source=googleshopping&utm_medium=cpc_elc&utm_content=zouzou&utm_campaign=pla-brand-elc2-ca&gclid=CjwKCAiA3JrQBRBtEiwAN7cEGhAH9NMCM24XHeiA4uqG6ZkX9wN7rjrKA-zmPuekBaCiioe_RPAt6xoCJ8cQAvD_BwE&cur_warehouse=CN).

[image]

Also teapot like the one you described seems like it would work as well will coarser grinds (like the one needed for a french press) but like a french press leaving the grinds for too long will result in an [overextracted bitter coffee](https://www.banggood.com/Stainless-Steel-Pour-Over-Coffee-Dripper-Reusable-Double-Mesh-Coffee-Maker-Cone-Filter-p-1178093.html?gmcCountry=CA&currency=CAD&createTmp=1&utm_source=googleshopping&utm_medium=cpc_elc&utm_content=zouzou&utm_campaign=pla-brand-elc2-ca&gclid=CjwKCAiA3JrQBRBtEiwAN7cEGhAH9NMCM24XHeiA4uqG6ZkX9wN7rjrKA-zmPuekBaCiioe_RPAt6xoCJ8cQAvD_BwE&cur_warehouse=CN). But keeping that in mind, it seems totally usable.

Hope this is helpful

Comment: Never knew there was something like that. I’ve only seen the ceramic ones that you still need a paper filter for. My issue is I’ve heard that This method can be very slow. I’m looking for a way to brew coffee in the morning before work when i don’t have that much time. How fast would something like this be?

Comment: @ZipZapJ I would presume as much time as it takes to make a standard pour over

Comment: As with paper filters, you want to adjust your grind size and pour to achieve your desired time. For most, this is somewhere between 2-3 minutes. So it is, in fact, quite fast.

Comment: @InstantCoffeeJedi bought the stainless steel dripper from osaka. Some of the easiest and best coffee Ive made! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion this calls for an AeroPress and a stainless steel filter disk. You will have zero waste, the AeroPress lasts forever due to the high quality plastic and with the steel filter you get a nice, full bodied cup of coffee.

Alternatively you could use the already mentioned steel mesh dripper. However I think for one cup of coffee the AeroPress is the way to go, also because the brewing time is a little bit less than for a drip coffee. Not that the difference would be huge though.

Comment: Hey thanks! Looked in to the aeropress and it looks great, but im on a budget. So i purchased a stainless steel pour over and it’s amazing!